# How to delete an element from an array using mongoose

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm a little bit stuck. I'm trying to delete an element from an array using mongoose. 
I used :

```
my_collection.update({
    user: req.query.user
}, {
    $pullAll: { //or $pull
        my_array: array[index] //= "elem1"
    }
});
```

Unfortunately it really doesn't work...

Here is my document, if it could help :

```
{
 "_id":"5a997cde9872f41085391f51",
 "my_array":
     ["elem1",
      "elem2",
      "elem3",
      "elem4"],
 "user":"rodolphe",
 "__v":0
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [$pullAll](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pullAll/), it requires an array argument, you passed a string.

This is the error I get when I run your code:
`MongoError: $pullAll requires an array argument but was given a string`

Make sure you console.log your errors with .catch()

```
// mock data
const req = { query: { user: "rodolphe" } }
const array = ["elem1"];
const index = 0;

// update record
Collection.update({
  user: req.query.user
}, {
  $pullAll: { //or $pull
      my_array: [array[index]] // WRAP WITH AN ARRAY
  }
})
  .then(res => console.log(res))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```